# NLog In a Class Libray can not write data to sqlite3 database

Tags: nlog

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

i config nlog in a c# class library named "common",added target to sqlite3 database, and add a other windows form application named "NLogtest", i was planned add "common" as a refrence in NLogtest. call loghelper class in common to write log, when write to log file it works fine, but when write to database it doesn't work.
so my question is can or can not config nlog in a class lib?

Comment: The [wiki-page](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target#systemdatasqlite-and-net-core) says that you should use `dbProvider="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, System.Data.SQLite"`

Comment: thanks to Rolf, the dbProvider it is a critical point.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Rolf, the dbProvider it is a critical point. and after teat i have found that NLog.Database.dll and System.Data.SQLite.dll have to exist in the base directory where the exe at. you can copy these two dll from somewhere else or import from Nuget manager.   then it would be work just fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdUqe.png)